# flutter web iOS device keyboard closing time show some jerk

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-web

I haven't used any external library for UI design.
Now the issue is when I close the keyboard at a time show one blank space and after 1 second  showing my app UI design. PFA one videos for issue.

[Video Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8qa36j0y1vgjbh/RPReplay_Final1666347569.MP4?dl=0)

This issue only facing in **flutter web** iOS device all **browser**.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.7, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 3.3.7 on channel stable at /Users/mac-19/FlutterSDK/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision e99c9c7cd9 (7 days ago), 2022-11-01 16:59:00 -0700
• Engine revision 857bd6b74c
• Dart version 2.18.4
• DevTools version 2.15.0
```

Sample code below and [Sample Video Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/83mzaltojzc9ceg/iOS_keyborad_issue.MP4?dl=0)

```html
class ScreenSignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenSignUp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScreenSignUp> createState() => _ScreenSignUpState();
}

class _ScreenSignUpState extends State<ScreenSignUp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text('SignUp'))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sample code added. Please check both of videos and code.